# Does a complete Lexicographical Ordering implies component-wise completeness of Orders (and vice versa)?

Tags: order-theory, economics

> **Question**
>
> Let $X$ be the product of $n$ sets $X_i$ each of which is ordered by $\succsim^L$. Show
> that the lexicographic order $\succsim^L$ is complete if and only if the component
> orders $\succsim_i$ are complete.
>
> *Note: All $X_i$ are ordered by $\succsim_i$*
>
> *Source*: FOUNDATIONS OF MATHEMATICAL ECONOMICS,
> Michael Carter, Exercise 1.35

For the $\Rightarrow$ part, I attempted a direct proof (by induction) but I couldn't bridge the gap in the inductive step in a succinct manner. Also I tried to tackle this proposition by proving its contra-positive which led me to nowhere. For the $\Leftarrow$ part, I think again an induction is necessary but again I couldn't close out the argument.

Comment: Could you add the fact that each $X_i$ is ordered by $>_i$? Just for it to be clearer.

Comment: @JulesBesson Done. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X = \varnothing$ it is direct let us consider that this is not the case.

---

So let us do the implication first.

We suppose that $\leq_L$ is complete. Let us take $k \leq n$ and $x,y \in X_k$. We just take $\forall i \neq k, \, x_i \in X_i$.
Since $\leq_L$ is complete, we have either
$$(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n) \leq_L (x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},y,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)$$
or
$$(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},y,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n) \leq_L (x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)$$
Since the first $k-1$ terms are the same, we have either $x \leq_k y$ or $y \leq_k x$ which means that $\leq_k$ is complete.

---

Now for the return, if all the $\leq_k$ are complete, let us suppose that there are $x=(x_i)_i$ and $y = (y_i)_i$ such that none of the following assertion are true:

- $x \leq_L y$
- $y \leq_L x$

That means that $x_1 = y_1$, otherwise we would have $x <_L y$ or $y <_L x$, and we can iterate (or you can make it an induction if you wish) with the same reasoning and get that $x_2 = y_2$, etc.
That means that $\forall k\leq n, \, x_k = y_k$, i.e. $x=y$ which is absurd. Hence $\leq_L$ is complete.